# strpos returning false with html entities even when using html_entity_decode

Tags: php, html-entities, strpos

I'm trying to search for a substring in a string that may or may not contain html entities such as   but even when using html_entity_decode() it still returns false

```
$str='online&nbsp;shop';
echo html_entity_decode($str);
//outputs: online shop
var_dump(strpos(html_entity_decode($str),'online shop'));
//outputs: bool(false)
```

Comment: I dont understand whats your wanted output. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&nbsp;` !== `space (20)`, it actully equals 2 byte NO-BREAK SPACE when decoded `C2 A0`.

`U+00A0 | \xc2\xa0 | &#xA0; | NO-BREAK SPACE`

You can test this with:

```
<?php
//
$str='&nbsp;';
var_dump(html_entity_decode($str));
```

Which will yield: `string(2) " "`

To fix replace the nbsp space with a normal one:

`var_dump(strpos(str_replace("\xc2\xa0", ' ', html_entity_decode($str)), 'online shop'));`

Result: `int(0)`

https://3v4l.org/WXTGR